# php regex question - test 10 digits long with first 5 same digit and second 5 another

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to port this java to php:

```
String _value = '1111122222';
if (_value.matches("(1{5}|2{5}|3{5}|4{5}|5{5}|6{5}|7{5}|8{5}|9{5}){2}")) {
    // check for number with the same first 5 and last 5 digits 
    return true;
}
```

As the comment suggests, I want to test for a string like '1111122222' or '5555566666'

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to do so:

```
preg_match('/^(1{5}|2{5}|3{5}|4{5}|5{5}|6{5}|7{5}|8{5}|9{5}){2}$/', $_value)
```

This returns the number of matches (i.e. either 0 or 1) or *false* if there was an error. Since the *String*’s `matches` method returns only *true* if the whole string matches the given pattern but `preg_match` doesn’t (a substring suffices), you need to set markers for the start and the end of the string with `^` and `$`.

You can also use this shorter regular expression:

```
^(?:(\d)\1{4}){2}$
```

And if the second sequence of numbers needs to be different from the former, use this:

```
^(\d)\1{4}(?!\1)(\d)\2{4}$
```

Comment: Good addition, but technically the OP doesn't anchor the match.

Comment: Or the even more confusing, `(?:(\d)\1{4}){2}`

Comment: @Jason McCreary: `matches` works differently in Java. It returns only true if the whole string matches the given pattern.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Been a while since I've written Java. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do:

```
$regex = '/(\d)\1{4}(\d)\2{4}/';
if (preg_match($regex, $value)) {
    return true;
}
```

Which should be much more efficient (and readable) than the regex you posted...

Or, an even shorter (and potentially cleaner) regex:

```
$regex = '/((\d)\2{4}){2}/';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = substr($_value, 0, 5);
$s = substr($_value, -5);
return (substr_count($f, $f[0]) == 5 && substr_count($s, $s[0]) == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion is below. `preg_match()` is the key: http://www.php.net/preg_match

```
$value = '1111122222';
if (preg_match('/^(1{5}|2{5}|3{5}|4{5}|5{5}|6{5}|7{5}|8{5}|9{5}){2}$/', $value)) {
    // check for number with the same first 5 and last 5 digits 
    return true;
}
```